# Can't get placeholder centered with moz-placeholder

Tags: firefox, center, placeholder

I need to center only the placeholder in Firefox, but doesn't work, the placeholder appears at left.

*CSS*******

```
:-moz-placeholder { text-align:center; } /*FF Old*/
::-moz-placeholder { text-align:center; } /*FF19+*/
::-webkit-input-placeholder{ text-align:center; } /*Chrome*/
:-ms-input-placeholder{ text-align:center; } /*IE10*/
```

*HTML*******

```
<input id="test" placeholder="test!">
```

You can try this bug with your FF23 and http://jsfiddle.net/eliaspizarro/ze4fV/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't exactly a bug. There is simply no spec yet that browser vendors can follow. It appears that instead [`:placeholder-shown`](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#placeholder) is on track to be standardized, although browsers do not support it right now.

The non-standard `::-moz-placeholder` is restricted in what style rules it may accept. `text-align` is not one of the accepted rules (The [rule](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/cc50ede32239/layout/style/nsCSSPropList.h#l2721) doesn't have the [`CSS_PROPERTY_APPLIES_TO_PLACEHOLDER`](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/cc50ede32239/layout/style/nsCSSProps.h#l184) bit set).

So you cannot use `text-align` with `::-moz-placeholder` at the time of writing.

However, you can `text-align` the whole `<input>`.

If you only want the placeholder text centered, but not entered text, then you may add some Javascript to set `.style.textAlign` according to the `<input>.value` when it changes. That's a nasty work-around, but should work. E.g. see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ze4fV/2/).

```
<input>.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
    this.style.textAlign = this.value === "" ? "center" : "left";
});
```